# "<" string in xml file

Tags: android

- I could not build my project in the android studio.
- the problem was ":app:mergeDebugResources" Error,
- after a while I found this error is caused by `android:text"<"`
- attribute in the XML file.after changing `"<"` character, the problem was solved.
- Is there any meaning for `"<"` String_character in XML language?
- The XML file is : (black lines of the code)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.1"
          android:orientation="vertical">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="TextView" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="TextView" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.18"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_clearEntity"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="CE"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="C"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="<"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_division"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="/"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.18"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_7"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="7"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_8"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="8"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_9"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="9"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_multiplication"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="X"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.18">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_4"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="4"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_5"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:text="5"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_6"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="6"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="-"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.18"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="1"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="2"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="3"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="+"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.18"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_sign"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="-/+"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_0"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="0"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_point"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="."
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_equal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.25"
              android:text="="
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="20dip" />
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

and:
[[image of error][image: 1]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Comment: Can you add a minimal example? No one wants to look at a hundred lines of code.

Comment: @James McLeod

I wrote "black lines of code" is desired lines

Comment: @vincrichaud 
I see that out of the double quotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are wondering how to get a `<` or a `>` in the text of a view.

For a less than <

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="&lt;"/>
```

For a greater than >

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="&gt;"/>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp